# RxSwift: binding PublishSubject to multiple buttons and receive sender

Tags: bind, rx-swift, publishsubject

I am working on an app that presents 26 (alphabet) buttons. Right now they're all connected to the same function in the `ViewController`, that in turn calls another function in the `ViewModel`, and finally this function calls `publishSubject.onNext()`. The `ViewController` subscribes to the `PublishSubject` and that's the whole circle.

The reason I did it this way, instead of binding the publish subject to the buttons' tap, is that I have to know who the sender is. Is there anyway to do so? If there isn't, is there a more intelligent design than mine in head?

Thanks!

Comment: You could use a like this filter{$0 == "A"}, if I'm understanding your design

Comment: Filter on what stream? What is $0? I need the ViewModel to know what button was pressed in the ViewController, that's the problem :)

Comment: i think you need to add some code for me to understand the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `PublishSubject` to send `String` and then each time a button is tapped, you can send the title of the button as the event data.

`publishSubject.onNext(sender.title)`

That way you can distinguish the sender from the `ViewModel` and keep your current design.

**UPDATE:**

After reading your question again I realized you are trying to achieve a more reactive way than what you currently have. So instead of pulling an `IBActions` from all the buttons, you can just have `IBOutlets` and on `viewDidLoad`  bind all those buttons to the `PublishSubject`. Something like this:

```
aButton
   .rx
   .tap.map { _ in 
      aButton.title
   }
   .bindTo(viewModel.buttonTapped)
   .disposed(by:disposeBag)
```

Comment: Thanks! exactly what I needed!